# Was the name "Angharad" in The Blue Sword an homage to the Chronicles of Prydain?

Tags: robin-mckinley, lloyd-alexander

*[The Blue Sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_Sword)* was a children's fantasy novel by Robin McKinley, published in 1982.  The main heroine is known as "Harry" through most of the book, and although it is clear from early on that that is not actually her given name, her actual name "Angharad," is not quoted until toward the middle of the story.

"Angharad" is not a common name, even in the parts of Britain with strong Celtic influences on the culture (west Wales, Cornwall, etc.); the same appears to be the case in the fictional mother country from which Harry has come.  On the other hand, "Angharad" is the mother of Eilonwy, the female lead in Lloyd Alexander's *Chronicles of Prydain*.  This led me to wonder whether McKinley's character was named after Alexander's.  Both authors tended to have highly competent female characters (Eilonwy is clearly more effective than the nominal protagonist Taran for the the first two books of their series), and I was wondering if there was any evidence that Harry's name was inspired by Alexander's writing.

Comment: I don't know the "answer" for a fact, but I strongly suspect that both McKinley and Alexander were using *The Mabinogion* as source material when they wanted to find some exotic-sounding names for some of their characters. That could bring the name "Angharad" to each author's attention, independently.

Comment: @Lorendiac *The Mabinogion* was certainly Alexander's source; he cribbed lots of names from it.  I was wondering if there was any evidence one way or the other about McKinley.

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't think I've actually read *The Blue Sword* since sometime in the mid-1990s. At this late date, I'm not sure if there was any other sign in it that McKinley had, at that time, recently been brushing up on her Welsh folklore. It was just the first explanation that popped into my head, since I have, in fact, read translations and adaptations of various portions of *The Mabinogion,* so it *seemed* likely that McKinley and Alexander had each latched onto that name for some such reason, rather than one swiping from the other's work.

Comment: I agree with almost all of your question.  But.  I would say that by the middle of the second book, T has grown up significantly.  Assuming leadership of the companions.  Going into the marshes, etc.  With and without the brooch to help him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia Angharad was a fairly common name for medieval Welsh royal and noble women.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angharad[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angharad)

That means that any writer interested in medieval Welsh history is likely to have read of one or more women named Angharad.  Any writer who sets a story in a society resembling medieval Wales is likely to give his female characters names based on medieval Welsh female names including Angharad.

Since the Welsh royal and noble families intermarried, anyone living in the prsent who can trace their ancestry to any medieval Welsh royalty and nobility are likely to be descended from at least one woman named Angharad.

For example Angharad ferch Meurig was the wife of King Rhodri the Great (c. 820-878) and thus the ancestress of most of the medieval Welsh kings.

Angharad ferch Owain ap Edwin of Tegeingl married King Gruffudd ap Cynan of Gwynedd (c. 1055-1137) a distant descendant of Angharad ferch Meurig and Rhodri the Great, and was the mother of several children including King Owain Gwynedd whose children included Iorwerth, father of Llywelyn The Great, father of Angharad ferch Llywelyn who married Maelgwn Fychan Deheubarth and had children who married, and were descended from three women named Angharad.

Llywelyn the Great had another daughter Elen who married secondly Sir Robert De Quincy and was the ancestress of many English nobles including the mothers of Richard Plantagenet Duke of York (1415-1460) and Henry VII.

Llywelyn the Great had another daughter Gwladus Ddu who married secondly Ralph de Mortimer and was the ancestress of many English nobles including Richard Plantagenet Duke of York (1415-1460), who was the first Yorkist claimant to the English throne.

Llywelyn the Great had another daughter Elen the younger who married secondly Domnall I, Earl of Mar, and had a daughter Isabella who married King Robert the Bruce and had a daughter Marjorie who was the mother of King Robert II the first Stuart king of Scotland.

So this means that any person who is descended from Welsh royalty and nobility,  and any person descended from Scottish kings beginning with Robert II (reigned 1371-1390) and any person descended from English kings after Edward IV (reigned 1460-1483) are descended from one or more women named Angharad.  And those groups include most people descended from late medieval English and Scottish nobility and many people descended from European royalty of the Renaissance and later periods.

Certainly many thousands of persons living today can trace their ancestry to women named Angharad.

.